# Stack Overflow notifies me for new comments on answers to subsequently deleted questions

Tags: support, comments, notifications

I have the following message in my inbox:

> 2 comments on [**Break point not being set in GDB**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6879024/break-point-not-being-set-in-gdb)
> that actually did work .Thanks !

But the link doesn't work, because the apparent scumbag deleted the question rather than awarding me the answer.

Note: After reading some other Meta questions I looked on https://stackoverflow.com/users/182705/neil?tab=responses but I didn't see either of the two comments there either.

So why clutter up my inbox with unusable links? Or is this just an incentive for me to earn another 5226 reputation points?

Comment: Bah, it happened again. This time, I fell for the April Fool's joke, and so my question got moderated, but not before it picked up three comments, which I can't read...

Answer (score 3):

Yep, that's the way it works, ghost comments happen quite a bit.  You still see them in your Inbox even after they were deleted (or the post they were attached to was).

Comment: I use those as a private message.  Comment responding to someone who made you realize your answer was stupid and useless, then delete your answer.

Comment: @John, I've done that before also, hoping that an experience user will know that's what is happening, but you have to keep them short since it only shows truncated.

Comment: Yes, unless your target recipient has over 10k.

Comment: @John, no, 10ks can't see deleted comments, you have to be a mod.  They can see the deleted questions and answers, and any previously undeleted comments on them.

Comment: Yes well I was referring to a not-deleted comment on a deleted *answer*.  10Ks can see that right?

Comment: @John Just as long as you're aware that all 10Ks (and moderators) can see it, so your private message isn't really all that private.

Comment: @Anna Good point.  Although, I try to act with the mindset that anyone can see everything I post on the internet.